# Settings - Resource URLs - Not finding specified extension folder

Tags: extension, error, resource-urls

As of civi 5.29.1, Civi is not finding the extensions in the specified directory.   (Directory has not changed and worked up to 5.28.  Just ran into problem for the first time installing 5.33.2 and worked backwards to find version it first occurs.)

Is this a known problem?    Solution required moving extensions to different directory - specifically the default directory.

Comment: Are you on WordPress and does your extension path setting include the [civicrm.files] token? There was a change in 5.29 that affected this situation.

Comment: Drupal 7 but we are using the civi.files token

Comment: do you know if there is a fix or an issue filed.

Comment: Probably this: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/wordpress/-/issues/66

Comment: Yes, @Demerit posted the issue that I was looking at. The code that changed as a result is at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/18068